# SyntaxError on world building using DSL

Tags: python

Im new to python and learning to code. Im currently experiencing an error in my world buidling.

here is the error:
SyntaxError: DSL is invalid!

The code I have for what im doing is below:

```
    world_dsl = """
|  |VT|  |
|  |EN|  |
|EN|ST|EN|
|  |EN|  |
"""
def is_dsl_valid(dsl):
    if dsl.count("|ST|") != 1:
        return False
    if dsl.count("|VT|") == 0:
        return False
    lines = dsl.splitlines()
    lines = [l for l in lines if 1]
    pipe_counts = [line.count("|") for line in lines]
    for count in pipe_counts:
        if count != pipe_counts[0]:
            return False

    return True

tile_type_dict = {"VT": VictoryTile,
                  "EN": EnemyTile,
                  "ST": StartTile,
                  "  ": None}

world_map = []

def parse_world_dsl():
    if not is_dsl_valid(world_dsl):
        raise SyntaxError("DSL is invalid!")

    dsl_lines = world.dsl.splitlines()
    dsl_lines = [x for x in dsl_lines if x]

    for y, fsl_row in enumerate(dsl_lines):
        row = []
        dsl_cells = dsl.row.split("|")
        dsl_cells = [c for c in dsl_cells if c]
        for x, dsl_cell in enumerate(dsl_cells):
            tile_type = tile_type_dict[dsl_cell]
            row.append(tile_type(x, y) if tile_type else none)

        world_map.append(row)
```

and in my game code that loads the world:

```
from player import Player
import world
from collections import OrderedDict


def play():
    print("Escape from Cave Terror!")
    world.parse_world_dsl()
    player = Player()
    while True:
        room = world.tile_at(player.x, player.y)
        print(room.intro_text())
        room.modify_player(player)
        choose_action(room, player)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The very first line in your `world_dsl` is empty, so the pipes-count check fails. You probably meant `lines = [l for l in lines if l]` (the last being lower-case letter L, not one). Voting to close for typo.

Comment: Since you plan to raise an exception anyway, I'd suggest raising that exception directly in the `is_dsl_valid` function with an appropriate error message. Also, I think `SyntaxError` should only be used for actual Python syntax errors; how about `ValueError` or some custom `DslSyntaxError`?